# Rails Twitter bot double post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, twitter, bots

I made a great Twitter bot that makes CrossFit workouts using this tutorial:
http://www.katelyndinkgrave.com/ruby/2016/01/31/civ-game-generator-twitterbot.html

however, keeps double posting; how do I make it only post once each time the script is run?

the Model is:

```
class Wod < ApplicationRecord

  def initialize
    @wod_type = WOD_TYPES.sample
    @time = time
    @rounds = rounds
    ...
  end

I've omitted code not relevant to the post...

  def print_wod
        if @wod_type == "EMOM"      
        "#{@wod_type} #{@time}:\n\n" +
        "#{@sets}\n\n" +
      "#{bbweight}" +
      "#{kbweight}" +
      "#{height}" +
      "#{slamweight}" +
      "#{wallweight}" +
      "\nFind more at: https://GymBull.com\n"
    else
        "#{@rounds}#{@wod_type}#{@time}:\n\n" +
      "#{@sets}\n\n" +
      "#{bbweight}" +
      "#{kbweight}" +
      "#{height}" +
      "#{slamweight}" +
      "#{wallweight}" +
      "\nFind more at: https://GymBull.com\n"
    end
  end

end
```

and the bot script run with (    rails r app/models/bot.rb ):

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"]
  config.consumer_secret     = ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
  config.access_token        = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  config.access_token_secret = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
end

wod = Wod.new
client.update(wod.print_wod)
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Heroku what's up; they said that every time you push to their server, it reloads every file, so it was running my script.

The solution was just to make a rake file and run that command instead of "rails r"